# Android resource file not found in java code

Tags: java, android

I am newbie in android. When I create android view flipper, the resource file are not found in Java code.

I attached screen shot for my issue.

[image]

Comment: what error it is showing ?file not found ,try to change the name of file it works for me some times or refresh

Comment: comment the lines that contain errors then clean the project..  the R file should be generated.

Comment: it showing slide_out_to_right cannot be resolved or is not a field. Thanks.

Comment: try  accessing it with R.id.slide_out_to_right and so on

Comment: Post relevant code and error log.

Answer (score 0):

you can clean the your project from Build tab in android studio

Comment: It is eclipse - not android studio